# Edit UITextField in UIKit so that the text can be edited via buttons

Tags: swift, uikit, uitextfield

I am currently developing a Notes app where I have a UITextField. When you select texts there is a popup where you can Format the text (see Screenshot). I want to have that functionality via buttons.

So I have a UITextfield where the user is typing something into and then I have e.g. a button which says bold and if the user clicks it the upcoming text should be bold as long as the button is enabled.

My issue is that the "old" text always goes bold. This is my current solution:

```
var isBoldEnabled = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set the initial font for the text field
    textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
}

@IBAction func boldButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    // Toggle the isBoldEnabled variable
    isBoldEnabled = !isBoldEnabled

    // Create a new attributed string with the existing text and the current font
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textField.text ?? "")
    let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: textField.font as Any]
    attributedString.addAttributes(attributes, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))

    // If the bold button is enabled, add the bold font attribute for the selected text
    if isBoldEnabled {
        let boldAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: textField.font!.pointSize) as Any]
        let selectedRange = textField.selectedTextRange
        if selectedRange != nil {
            let range = textField.selectedRange
            attributedString.addAttributes(boldAttributes, range: NSRange(location: range.location, length: range.length))
        }
    }

    // Set the attributed text to the text field
    textField.attributedText = attributedString
}
```

Has anyone a better approach how this functionality can be enabled with only changing the upcoming typing?
Thanks all[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how much you want to do...

For complex, full-featured "rich-text editing" I'd suggest searching for already build solutions - lot's of open-source out there. If you can't find one to do exactly what you need, I'm sure you could find one close enough that you could go through the code and edit it to suit your needs.

For a fairly simple implementation, you can set the text field's `.typingAttributes` - see Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619632-typingattributes).

Here's a very quick example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let textField = UITextField()
    
    let normalFont: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .regular)
    let boldFont: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .bold)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        
        textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        textField.font = normalFont
        
        let v = UILabel()
        v.text = "Bold on/off"
        
        let sw = UISwitch()
        
        let ctrlStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [v, sw])
        ctrlStack.spacing = 8
        
        ctrlStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(ctrlStack)
        
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(textField)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            ctrlStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            ctrlStack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            
            textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ctrlStack.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            textField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),

        ])
        
        sw.addTarget(self, action: #selector(swChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    }
    
    @objc func swChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        textField.typingAttributes?[NSAttributedString.Key.font] = sender.isOn ? boldFont : normalFont
    }
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

tap the switch to turn bold "On" and type a little more:

[image]

turn bold "Off" and type some more:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my issues. Such a simple but so effective solution!

Answer (score 0):

When you try to "unbold" your text, you're setting default font to attributed string as font from your textfield

```
UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: textField.font!.pointSize) as Any
```

which was previously set as **bold**

So, change your code to

```
var isBoldEnabled = false
let defaultFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set the initial font for the text field
    textField.font = defaultFont
}

@IBAction func boldButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    // Toggle the isBoldEnabled variable
    isBoldEnabled = !isBoldEnabled

    // Create a new attributed string with the existing text and the current font
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textField.text ?? "")
    let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: defaultFont as Any]
    attributedString.addAttributes(attributes, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But then the issue is that every text already written gets bold and that what will be written next is not bold...

Comment: So basically when I "unbold" it, it doesn't stay also bold. So the bold is not saved and everything goes back to unbold. Probably is because the Font for the rest is set to default, but is there a way to save that bold for the text?